# Использование метода фабрики, принимающего строку

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java, методы

Здравствуйте!
Впервые(!) пришлось делать метод фабрику, поэтому решил спросить у более опытных людей, хорошо ли у меня получилось. Метод делает обратное toString преобразование, т.е.:
на входе получает строку, которую надо разобрать, а на выходе объект.

```
public static PortConfig valueOf(String s) {

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
        List<String> stArray = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            stArray.add(st.nextToken());
        }

        System.out.println("получили массив " + stArray.toString());

        Configuration.PortConfig pc = new PortConfig();

        pc.setPort(stArray.get(0));
        pc.setBaudRate(Integer.parseInt(stArray.get(1)));
        pc.setDataBits(Integer.parseInt(stArray.get(2)));
        pc.setStopBits(Integer.parseInt(stArray.get(3)));
        pc.setParity(Integer.parseInt(stArray.get(4)));
        pc.setFlowControl(Integer.parseInt(stArray.get(5)));

        System.out.println(pc.toString());

        return pc;
    }
```

Хочу услышать критику.

Comment: имхо лучше метод назвать parse или parseStr или parseConfigStr (я бы выбрал первый)

Answer (score 3):

*Вообще неплохо, но всегда есть возможность улучшить код:*

- Семантика вашего метода скорее подразумевает название `fromString`, нежели не очень понятное `valueOf`.
- То, что вы написали *(если следовать терминологии `Gang Of Four [GOF]`)* - это никак не `factory method,` а просто `named constructor`. Что, в общем-то, не умаляет практической ценности данного метода.
- Вызовы к `System.out.println` имеет смысл заменить на любой адекватный подход к логированию типа `logger.debug("Whatever...")`. Смотрите в сторону `java.util.logging` и `log4j`.
- Следующий фрагмент кода напрашивается на вынос в отдельный статический метод, поскольку не имеет никакой прямой связи с конструированием объекта. Возможное название - `splitStringToTokens`.

> ```
> StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
> List<String> stArray = new ArrayList<String>();
>
> while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
>     stArray.add(st.nextToken());
> }
> ```

- Необходимо отдельно отметить типы исключений, которые может порождать ваш метод. Скажем, как и где вы собираетесь обрабатывать ситуацию, если `parseInt` выкинет `NumberFormatException`?
- Способ конструирования вашего объекта `Configuration.PortConfig`, лично я бы заменил на [**`Fluent Builder`**](http://refactormycode.com/codes/194-fluent-builder).

> В текущей реализации совершенно
> непонятно, является ли объект,
> полученный с помощью вызова `new PortConfig()`
> *корректным* или нет. И, что самое
> главное - требуются ли все вызовы
> `setXyz` для того, чтобы перевести его
> *в корректное состояние*?
>
> Более подробно
> по этому поводу можете прочитать в
> [Joshua Bloch - Effective Java, **Item
> 2.**](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/)

- **Покройте написанный метод юнит-тестами.**
- Возможно, стоит вообще заменить ваш текущий подход к сохранению состояния объекта с помощью [**сериализации**](http://habrahabr.ru/post/60317/)?

Comment: п.4 Токенайзер лучше вообще выкинуть.

    List<String> stArray = Arrays.asList(s.split(","));

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал так:

```
public final class ConfigurationFactory
{
    // ненадо нам его создавать
    private ConfigurationFactory ()
    {
        // nothing to do
    }

    public static NetworkConfig parseNetworkConfig ( final String data )
    {
        final List < String > list = parseTokens ( data ) ;

        return new NetworkConfig ( Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 0 ) ), Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 1 ) ),
                Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 2 ) ), Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 3 ) ),
                Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 4 ) ), Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 5 ) ) ) ;
    }

    public static DatabaseConfig parseDatabaseConfig ( final String data )
    {
        final List < String > list = parseTokens ( data ) ;

        return new DatabaseConfig ( Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 0 ) ), Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 1 ) ),
                Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 2 ) ), Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 3 ) ),
                Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 4 ) ), Integer.parseInt ( list.get ( 5 ) ) ) ;
    }

    // так этот метод может использоватся для того чтоб спарсить строку
    // во время создания любого конфига
    private static List < String > parseTokens ( final String data )
    {
        final StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer ( data, "," ) ;
        final List < String > list = new LinkedList < String > () ;

        while ( st.hasMoreTokens () )
        {
            list.add ( st.nextToken () ) ;
        }
        return list ;
    }

}

public class NetworkConfig
{
    // этот будет использоватся для конструирования обьекта с помощью геттеров
    public NetworkConfig ()
    {
    }

    // этот можно в принцыпе сделать и приватным конструктором
    public NetworkConfig ( int port, int baudRate, int dataBits, int stopBits, int parity, int flowControl )
    {
    }

    // геттеры сеттеры и остальной функционал

    /**
     * Этот метод должен возвращать точно такую ще строку которую вы подаете на вход метода parse
     */
    @Override
    public String toString ()
    {
        return super.toString () ;
    }

}

// содержимое класса абсолютно идентичное networkconfig, разница только в хранимых полях
public class DatabaseConfig
{
    public DatabaseConfig ( int parseInt, int parseInt2, int parseInt3, int parseInt4, int parseInt5, int parseInt6 )
    {
    }

}
```

суть в том что вы разделяете логику и хранение данных. с одной стороны у вас есть класс который отвечает за парсинг и инициализацию обьектов с другой стороны простые java бины для хранения данных

второй вариант попроще - хранить любую конфигурацию в мапе. только в этом случае у вас строка конфигурации должна иметь вид:
`key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;key4=value4;`

пример кода:

```
public final class ConfigurationFactory
{
  public static Map<String, String> parseConfig (String data) {...};
}

использование Map - довольно простое, но не совсем удобное решение. можно завернуть в класс:
class Config
{
  Map<String, String> map = null;

  // здесь обязательно надо добавить проверку на null
  public Config (Map<String, String> map) {this.map = map;}

  public void put(String key, String value) {map.put(key, value);};

  public String get(String key) {return map.get(key);}

  // добавляем проверку на null после map.get(key)
  public String getInt(String key) {return Integer.parseInt(map.get(key));}

  // добавляем проверку на null после map.get(key)
  public String getInteger(String key) {return Integer.valueOf(map.get(key));}

  // другие методы с приведением типов
}
```